# Evaluate a conditional as well as bind its result in pattern match?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am repeatedly finding myself writing something similar to this:

```
c match {
  case c if lengthyEvaluation1(c) > 0 => lengthyEvaluation1(c).toString
  case c if lengthyEvaluation2(c) > 0 => lengthyEvaluation2(c).toString
}
```

Where `lengthyEvaluation1` and `lengthyEvaluation2` are functions that have non-negligible calculation time, and which are obviously being called twice. Is there some way to both create a new variable that is the result of `lengthyEvaluation(c)`, and also check the conditional against this? In python there is the so-called 'expression statement' for this purpose, although it's recent and a bit controversial. Or is this is a bad idiom to be using in the first place?

Comment: Pattern matching is independent from `c` in this case. I don't really see the point using it over `if`.

Comment: I'm with @Andronicus. This is pattern matching just for the heck of it. There's no pattern matching happening here.

Comment: @Andronicus: yes, that seems a fair statement. I like the expressiveness of pattern matches, probably a bit too much, and simple imperative code now feels a bit lame. But this seems like a case where a couple of if statements might work better.

Comment: @Chrisper `if` does not have to be a statement in scala, if it's an expression, then it's not imperative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is one of the weaknesses of Scala's pattern matching syntax. What you can do is use a custom extractor:

```scala
class FunctionExtractor[A, B](f: A => B) {
  def unapply(a: A): Option[B] = Some(f(a))
}
val LengthyEvaluation1 = new FunctionExtractor(lengthyEvaluation1)
val LengthyEvaluation2 = new FunctionExtractor(lengthyEvaluation2)

c match {
  case LengthyEvaluation1(res) if res > 0 => res.toString
  case LengthyEvaluation2(res) if res > 0 => res.toString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider **lazy** value definition, for example

```
lazy val a = lengthyEvaluation1(c)
lazy val b = lengthyEvaluation2(c) 

if (a > 0) 
  // use a
else if (b > 0)
  // use b
else
  ???
```